# Can't show Mapbox on Dialog Material UI

Tags: reactjs, dialog, material-ui, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Please consider some code below:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Dialog } from '@material-ui/core';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

export default function UseMapbox() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  mapboxgl.accessToken = token;
  const mapRef = React.useRef();

 
  useEffect(() => {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapRef.current,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [10, 10],
      zoom: 9
    });
  }, []);


  return (
    <Dialog
      open
      onClose={onClose}
    >

      <div ref={mapRef} className={classes.map} />
    </Dialog>
  );
}
```

The problem I'm facing is **mapRef.current** is undefined.
If I don't use **Dialog**, it works properly. so I think useEffect had run before Dialog was rendered completely.

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example (better on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/))

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when using mapbox-gl directly.

I solved it by adding a wrapper instead of referencing it directly as such:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Dialog } from '@material-ui/core';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

export default function UseMapbox() {
  return (
    <Dialog open onClose={onClose}>
      <MapboxWrapper />
    </Dialog>
  );
}

const MapboxWrapper = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapRef.current,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [10, 10],
      zoom: 9
    });
  }, []);


  return <div ref={mapRef} className={classes.map} />
}
```